# Translatable doctrine array fieds

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, translate

I have a working entity with a field (of type ArrayCollection) that maps with doctrine to a column of type array.

Now I need this field to be translatable (doctrine behaviors) but I'm getting a **Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array** ConversionException when fetching an untranslated locale.

How can I keep the array functionality and make it translatable?

### The property declaration within the entity Product:

```php
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(name="categories", type="array")
 */
private $categories;
```

### **The controller action:**

```php
// ... Controller ProductController nitty gritty

public function showAction(Request $request, $id, $locale)
{
    // omitted stuff, load $product by $id

    $product->setTranslatableLocale($locale); // load translations
    $em->refresh($product);

    return $this->render('AcmeExampleBundle:Product:show.html.twig', [
        'product' => $product
    ]);
}
```

### **The exception:**

> **ConversionException**
>
> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

**The exception stack trace:** [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5RK7AKwC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. I was trying to set my own `{locale}` route segment when I should have been using native `{_locale}` (notice the underscore - [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-locale-url)).

If you let symfony handle locales through routing, [translatable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) will transparently handle entity translations (including form submissions), and there is no need for calling `$entity::setTranslatableLocale()` nor `EntityManager::refresh()`.

No need for special treatment to arrays fields, they translate seamlessly out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to convert an empty string from the database to an array. The problem comes from the `categories` column. Instead of a serialized empty array, this column contains empty values.

A possible solution is to replace the empty string with the expected array as follow :

```
UPDATE `product` SET categories="a:0:{}" WHERE categories= "";
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, the exceptions is rather clear. In the context of fetching an entity with untranslated fields from the database, I don't understand why I should be performing any write operations...

Comment: @Phil Thomas if this solved your issue, accept blackbishop 's answer

Comment: sorry, I thought, from your comment, that the answer solved your issue :D sorry again!